# java.net.UnknownHostException at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, eclipse, api, exception

I am trying to create an application that connects to an API. Rigth now I am trying to connect to the API and print out the result. However, for some reason I keep getting this following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.data.goteborg.se 
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) 
   at TestAPI.getHTML(TestAPI.java:14) 
   at TestAPI.main(TestAPI.java:29)
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Bellow is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

//import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestAPI {


    public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             result.append(line);
          }
        rd.close();
        return result.toString(); // JSON Object
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Test1");

         String data;
         data = getHTML("http://data.goteborg.se/AirQualityService/v1.0/LatestMeasurement/"
                + "myAPIkey?format=Json");
         System.out.println(data);



    }

}
```

Comment: does the URL work from a browser for you?

Comment: @BrianPipa Yes, It does.

Comment: @BrianPipa Any idea why it is not working from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to [www.data.goteborg.se](http://www.data.goteborg.se).
I think you're dealing with a dns lookup failure.

In [this link](http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/01/Dns-Probe-Finished-NxDomain.html) you can find 3 methods for fixing the *DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN* error.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look on the link.

Comment: I can connect to the api link but can't connect to www.data.goteborg.se 

Maybe I need permisssion in order to be able to connect to the api? I am using my work connection.